# Migrating SharePoint 2010 Custom Workflows

Tags: workflow

I have SharePoint 2010 farm where there are custom workflows created for a few applications running on different site collections. I need to migrate the entire site collection along with the custom components (webparts & workflows) to a new SharePoint 2010 server farm.

To my current understanding , I'm planning to follow these steps to achieve the same , however I am not sure if I am missing something over here or if this is going to work or not.

NEW FARM 
1) Create a new web application 
2) Create a new site collection by attaching the content database from the old farm. This content database will have the site collections and the workflow instances. 
3) Deploy all custom wsps necessary for the web parts and workflows.
4) Activate features on the new site collection by site actions > site settings > site collection features.

Please suggest if the above sequence of activities is correct or not. Are there any chances of things breaking or loosing workflow instances from one SharePoint 2010 farm to another by following the above method.

Comment: We have migrate 15000+ running custom workflows using the attach/detach method as decribe by Per. Everything works fine.

Just: do test before... that's not difficult and could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move step 3 before step 2 as you want the webparts, workflows, ... before you add the content database using them

Remove step 4 as they are already activated

Should work, but this is software so there is alway a risk of something breaking. It very much depend on external dependencies of the workflows.

Comment: Thanks Per for the answer. I was actually having the same notion at the back of my mind about the sequence of steps , however wasn't sure of the same. Now I'm confident that this will  work with the way you suggested. Thanks again!!